# missing cet_enable field in product type settings (Commerce Event Ticket)

Tags: 7, commerce, debugging

I have installed the [Commerce Event Ticket](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_event_ticket) module along with any requirements and have enabled it. I see the following under column `description` in  `admin/modules`:

> Allows tickets (with unique barcodes) to be generated for Commerce purchases.
>
> Version: 7.x-1.0-beta3
>
> Requires: Entity API (enabled), Commerce (enabled), System (enabled), Rules
>   (enabled), Entity tokens (enabled), Product (enabled), Price (enabled), Customer (enabled), Address Field (enabled), Chaos tools (enabled), Line Item (enabled), Order (enabled), Commerce UI (enabled), Checkout (enabled), Cart (enabled), Product Pricing (enabled), Product Reference (enabled), Options (enabled), Field (enabled), Field SQL storage (enabled), Views (enabled), Order UI (enabled), Field UI (enabled), Product UI (enabled), Customer UI (enabled), Views Bulk Operations (enabled)
>
> Required by: Commerce Event Ticket PDF (disabled), Commerce Event Ticket Mail (disabled), Commerce Event Ticket Services (disabled)

Now, when I add a new product type (`commerce/products/types/add`) or go to `Manage Fields` of an existing product type, I do not get an existing field `cet_enable`. The list of available existing fields in the list box only contains:

```
<select class="field-select form-select" id="edit-fields-add-existing-field-field-name" name="fields[_add_existing_field][field_name]">
<option value="" selected="selected">- Select an existing field -</option>
<option value="field_link_to_page">Boolean: field_link_to_page (Link to page)</option>
<option value="field_date">Date: field_date (Date)</option>
<option value="field_eventdate">Date: field_eventdate (Date)</option>
<option value="field_price">Float: field_price (Price)</option>
<option value="field_image">Image: field_image (Image)</option>
<option value="field_img">Image: field_img (Image Gallery)</option>
<option value="field_myimage">Image: field_myimage (MyImage)</option>
<option value="uc_catalog_image">Image: uc_catalog_image (Image)</option>
<option value="uc_product_image">Image: uc_product_image (Image)</option>
<option value="field_table_description">Long text: field_table_description (Event Description)</option>
<option value="field_product_reference">Product reference: field_product_reference (Product reference)</option>
<option value="field_tags">Term reference: field_tags (Tags)</option>
<option value="taxonomy_catalog">Term reference: taxonomy_catalog (Catalog)</option>
<option value="field_external_link">Text: field_external_link (External link (leave empty for no link or use abov...</option></select>
```

How do I get access to the `cet_enable` field?
This is after a core update to 7.34

I've filed a bug with the module but am also interested in how I can troubleshoot this best myself???
Thanks for hints and tips!

Answer (score 0):

Could this be related to some type of permission that is still missing? Also, consider adding a LINK in your question to point to the issue you created (it may help to further enhance this question also).

Did you receive any eMails by using this module?